# Firefox Temp files

Tags: firefox

I am in the middle of creating a CCleaner like application for unix based/styled systems.

I am having trouble finding out exactly where Firefox holds its temporary files, and those in the Firefox dev community don't seem to willing to help me find out where.

I know atleast in Linux(which is my focus now), the temp files are held in

```
/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/
```

Most of the temp files are held in the Cache directory, but not all.  So do any of you have any tips or documentation of where extacly the temp files are stored.

Comment: check the directory /tmp

Comment: Im pretty sure firefox doesn't use /tmp.  Ive used firefox and see no change to /tmp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you have ~/.mozilla/firefox/profile.default/Cache to hold your cache, but you can also check the location set by [browser.cache.disk.parent_directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.disk.parent_directory).

You can find the user.js or/and prefs.js in the user's current directory (~/.mozilla/firefox/profile.default/).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox on windows use SQLLite to store history and such like and i use code to kill the FireFox process and then it deletes all but one of the sqllite files so that you don't losse bookmarks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Text;

namespace Fidling
{
    public static class SpywareRemoval
    {
        private static void RemoveSpywareFiles(string RootPath, string Path,bool Recursive)
        {
            string FullPath = RootPath + Path + "\\";
            if (Directory.Exists(FullPath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo DInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FullPath);
                FileAttributes Attr = DInfo.Attributes;
                DInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                foreach (string FileName in Directory.GetFiles(FullPath))
                {
                    RemoveSpywareFile(FileName);
                }
                if (Recursive)
                {
                    foreach (string DirName in Directory.GetDirectories(FullPath))
                    {
                        RemoveSpywareFiles("", DirName, true);
                        try { Directory.Delete(DirName); }catch { }
                    }
                }
                DInfo.Attributes = Attr;
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveSpywareFile(string FileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                try { File.Delete(FileName); }catch { }//Locked by something and you can forget trying to delete index.dat files this way
            }
        }

        private static void DeleteFireFoxFiles(string FireFoxPath)
        {
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "cookies.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "content-prefs.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "downloads.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "formhistory.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "search.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "signons.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "search.json");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "permissions.sqlite");
        }

        public static void RunCleanup()
        {
            try { KillProcess("iexplore"); }
            catch { }//Need to stop incase they have locked the files we want to delete
            try { KillProcess("FireFox"); }
            catch { }//Need to stop incase they have locked the files we want to delete
            string RootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).ToLower().Replace("documents", "");
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects",false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\#local", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files", false);//Not working
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.History), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Wer", true);  
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches", false);          
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Temp", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\LocalLow\Apple Computer\QuickTime\downloads", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache", false);
            if (Directory.Exists(RootPath + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"))
            {
                string FireFoxPath = RootPath + @"AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\";
                DeleteFireFoxFiles(FireFoxPath);
                foreach (string SubPath in Directory.GetDirectories(FireFoxPath))
                {
                    DeleteFireFoxFiles(SubPath + "\\");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void KillProcess(string ProcessName)
        {//We ned to kill Internet explorer and Firefox to stop them locking files
            ProcessName = ProcessName.ToLower();
            foreach (Process P in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (P.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith(ProcessName))
                    P.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code also remove flash shared cookies and lots more but i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Temp Files are in (the hidden directory) `~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/[profile_name]`. At least in openSuSE Linux for any recent version.